# Updating a table with a random 'WHERE' CLAUSE in mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to update a random fileName in my table `k_pictures`.  Right now, the code below gets a random fileName from the table, and writes it to a text file. Then, it displays the fileName (fileName is an image).

What it doesn't do is UPDATE properly in my update query (as seen in the code below).  What I would like it to do is update the column `caption` with the original random fileName acting as the `WHERE` clause that I had selected with this code

```
$getThis = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `k_pictures` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

I know, it's a little confusing.

The update query currently just updates a random `caption` column and by the correct one that was selected randomly with this code:

```
$getThis = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `k_pictures` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Update query:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE k_pictures SET caption = '" . $caption . "' WHERE fileName = '" . $official . "' LIMIT 1") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Code:

```
 <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'caption');

    $getThis = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `k_pictures` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

        while($row = $getThis->fetch_assoc()) {
          date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
          $currentTime = date('h:i:s:U');
          $filename = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/kaption/caption/data/" . $currentTime . ".txt";
          $fp = fopen($filename, 'a+');

          fwrite($fp, $row['fileName']);

          fclose($fp);

          $fh = fopen($filename, 'r');

          $official = fread($fh, filesize($filename));

          fclose($fh);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='../p/$official' height='500px' width='500px'></td>";
            echo "</tr>\n";
            $getCaption = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `k_pictures` WHERE fileName = '" . $official . "'") or die($mysqli->error);
            while($retrieve = $getCaption->fetch_array()) {
              if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $caption = $_POST['caption'];
                header('Location: ../home/');
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE k_pictures SET caption = '" . $caption . "' WHERE fileName = '" . $official . "' LIMIT 1") or die($mysqli->error);
              }

                echo "<h3>" . $retrieve['caption'] . "</h3>";
              }
            }

    ?>
```

Comment: No idea really. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Does your version of MySQL support UPDATE with LIMIT and/or is k_pictures a multi-table view?

Comment: It does support it, otherwise it would kick out an error.